# CartThrob Cart Items Info without currency formatting

Tags: cartthrob

We're using **CartThrob Pro 2.7** and **EE 2.10**.  Is there a way to output the item subtotal without the currency formatting?  We've tried:

```
{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info number_format="yes"}

{item_subtotal}

{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
```

but it still applies the currency symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the parameter prefix=""

```
{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info number_format="yes" prefix=""}
{item_subtotal}
{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
```

the prefix tag is for manually specifying the currency symbol or prefixing the amounts with whatever you need. Setting it to "" means use no symbol.